# html 5 doc mode still opening up in quirks

Tags: html, doctype

I'm working on a WordPress site and even when I delcare html5 as the docmode, the site still forces to open in quirks in IE9 and 8. The url is: http://teknikor.bethmotta.com

my header.php contains the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Any ideas on why this is still opening in Quirks? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just viewed the site and you've got about 38 lines of HTML above your doctype, which looks to be related to Google Analytics.  IE's going to want the doctype to be the first line of source, I believe.

Comment: ah ok... I'll have to figure out where that is coming from... my header file has the doctype as the first line. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I'd look for how you're including Google Analytics, since that's what the code looks like it's for.

Comment: This worked! Each page tempalte had a duplicate <head> tag and had GA installed in there. Thanks for your help!